# Why doesn't "ScreenOrientation: change event" work on the mobile web (iOS Safari)?

Tags: javascript, orientation, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

Why doesn't `ScreenOrientation: change event` work on the mobile web (iOS Safari)?
I've made a web page and I want to reload the page whenever the orientation has been changed on a mobile. but `location.reload();` is not working. I have tried `alert("?");` but it's also not working.

The code that I used is below.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      location.reload();
    });
});
```

At first, I used `orientationchange`. but I found it's deprecated and has one error which is showing the pop-up that asks **"if you want to download the page"** when orientation has been changed on iOS mobile phone  (PC doesn't have that error). Now I'm using `ScreenOrientation: change event` instead.

I found that it only works on PC, and doesn't work on my mobile phone (iOS 16.6 Safari).

As I searched `ScreenOrientation: change event`, it should work on both mobile and PC.

Does anyone know why `screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", (event)` is not working on the mobile and what can I do?